# Is mcrypt deprecated?

Tags: command-line

up to today it was, that command passwd involves mcrypt.

According to a friend, mcrypt would be deprecated and soon substituted by

OpenSSL - is this true ?

Answer (score 3):

It's irrelevant.

If you have a look in `/etc/login.defs`, you'll find the following line:

```
ENCRYPT_METHOD SHA512
```

This is specifies that SHA512 shall be used for password hashing on Ubuntu for user logins. By default, 5000 rounds are used.

How the `passwd` program handles this hashing internally is irrelevant for the security of the hashed passwords.

It also appears that passwd in Ubuntu uses `crypt`, not `mcrypt`.

Switching to OpenSSL sounds unlikely. OpenSSL is a huge library, which supports lots of algorithms, and has a ton of dependencies. This functionality is superfluous for the use in `passwd`.

I could not find any references to this in [the mailing lists of the package](https://alioth-lists.debian.net/pipermail/pkg-shadow-devel/), nor [changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-passwd/+changelog) for upcoming Cosmic Cuttlefish.

So in short; no. `passwd` is not changing to OpenSSL. It's not using mcrypt either, by the looks of it.

mcrypt *is* deprecated, as no active development has happened for years, and OpenSSL may be used as a replacement. There's also other replacements, such as bcrypt.

Comment: @vidario - in files of mcrypt is said, that mcrypt substitutes former crypt... but thank you for your enlightening answer. Maybe you can tell me, how to link command passwd to command mcrypt ?!